# how hold /unhold call with Asterisk-java?

Tags: java, asteriskami

Once connected to the AMI using java-asterisk i create a call :

```
  OriginateAction originateAction;
    ManagerResponse originateResponse;
    getEvent event = new getEvent();
    SipShowPeerAction peer = new SipShowPeerAction();
    peer.setPeer("phone1");
    managerConnection.addEventListener(event);
    originateAction = new OriginateAction();
    ParkAction park = new ParkAction();
    originateAction.setChannel("SIP/mark");
    originateAction.setCallerId("<6002>");
    originateAction.setContext("default");
    originateAction.setPriority(new Integer(1));
    originateAction.setExten("1304");

    managerConnection.login();
    managerConnection.addEventListener(event);
    originateResponse = managerConnection.sendAction(peer);

    originateResponse = managerConnection.sendAction(originateAction, 30000);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    park.setActionId(originateAction.getActionId());

    managerConnection.logoff();
```

I want to hold and unhold the current call using Asterisk-java , i checket in net i found that i have to use ParkAction but i dont really understand the concept ?
if someone have an idea ?

Comment: logging is almost always helpful.  can you post logs of connecting to the AMI?  Particularly from the client side.  Ie, just put some system.out lines in the above and paste the results.